# The variables created using jupyter (.ipynb) do not work on .py files in vscode (in the same environment in WSL). Different terminals?

Tags: python, visual-studio, jupyter-notebook, environment-variables, conda

Context: I'm using vscode with WSL and I also use conda for environment management.

I'm trying to create a variable in a jupyter notebook, let's say `x = [10, 20]`, and then use that same variable in a .py file (not on jupyter notebooks). I'm already using the same environment on both, but the terminal/kernel I believe is different for each. I believe this because when I run a cell on jupyter notebook, nothing happens on the terminal. However, when I run on .py files, the terminal runs the code I selected.

I would like to see the terminal running something for jupyter (.ipynb) and also for my .py files.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The most direct route to do what you describe in your first sentence is to run Jupyter and set x in your notebook with that code. Then you run your script **from in side the notebook** (or you could do the same with IPython in a terminal by first invoking IPython in your terminal by typing `ipython`) in the same namespace as your already run code. You do that with the `-i` flag for interactive. So in the notebook (or console) `%run -i my_script.py` where your replace `my_script.py` with your script and even the path to it if you need that.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know it was possible to do that.

Comment: Yes, it is how you can easily develop a script in conjunction with a notebook/IPython console to test things. Or how you can use a notebook/IPython console to set settings prior to executing a script that does most of the work. Thus keeping the bulk of the code in the script and making a cleaner interface where you walk users through initiating a process that has a lot of settings or for situations where you have a lot of code you want to be more behind-the-scenes without overwhelming them. See [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run)

Comment: Thanks! that's a very good compromise for what I was looking for

Comment: There are other ways, too, to address your first sentence. You could use import to bring in the code from the notebook to the Python script that you are running in the terminal. See about `ipynb` or `importnb` [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/package-for-importing-jupyter-notebooks-as-modules/12923/2). If it was only certain cells, you can use nbformat to parse them out of the notebook, save them as a script and import that code. In a slightly different variation, you can use the command line to execute a notebook. But since you said you were trying to combine code in ....

Comment: <continued> a notebook with code in a script that isn't really want you want because executing the notebook would be isolated from the execution of the script.